# Beamer: tableofcontents with page numbers

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, page-numbering

How do I get page numbers / slide numbers in the tableofcontents in a beamer presentation?

Comment: Thank Gonzalo Medina for your wonderful code. How to show frame numbers up to subsubsections in the table of contents? The code of Gonzalo only shows frame numbers of sections and subsections. If a table of contents has subsubsections. These subsubsections don't have their frame numbers in TOC. I guess one can modify the above code. However, I am just a beginner to beamer. So any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to redefine `\beamer@section` and `\beamer@subsection` as defined in `beamerbasesection.sty` to include the corresponding page number; here's an example showing the necessary redefinition in action:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%

\def\beamer@subsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionentry{\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsection}}%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}%
    }%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \edef\subsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{3}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}test1\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}test2\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test3\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}test4\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test5\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}test6\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}test7\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test8\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test9\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}test10\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And an image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Here's a variation producing the frame number in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\newcounter{sectionpage}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
    \setcounter{sectionpage}{\insertframenumber}\stepcounter{sectionpage}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2\hfill\thesectionpage}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%

\def\beamer@subsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsection{#1}%
    \setcounter{sectionpage}{\insertframenumber}\stepcounter{sectionpage}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{#2\hfill\thesectionpage}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionentry{\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsection}}%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}%
    }%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \edef\subsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{3}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}

\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}test1\pause test11\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}test2\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test3\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}test4\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test5\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}test6\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame}test7\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test8\end{frame}
\begin{frame}test9\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame}test10\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that partly answers my questions. But this solution doesn't work correctly if I use the \pause command.

Comment: @Ivo you said you wanted the *page* number in your question and my solution does exactly that. I guess that now you want the *frame* number instead, so  I've added a new code showing this number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching the matter, and there seems to be no satisfying answer.

However, if your purpose for the pagenumber/slide numbers is for **printing a handout**,

```
    \documentclass[options]{scrartcl} 
    \usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

does this when you replace it for \documentclass{beamer}.

Comment: It gives the pagenumbers for (sub)sections and the like in the Table of Content.

Comment: What if the OP really wants the page number in a presentation?

Comment: Yes, I want the **slide number in the presentation**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/64/add-tableofcontents-styles-that-display

Comment: In October 2017, this link is dead.

Comment: new link is https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/64 (cannot edit because the with the new link the post does not have the minimal number of characters)