# How to solve the error: No counter 'sectionpage' defined

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, counters, knitr, markdown

I'm trying to use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66230/90587) answer from a previous question to get frame numbers in a table of content in a beamer presentation made in RStudio with R Markdown and knitr (see file below; in in_header.tex the code from the answer I've linked to is inserted, can also be seen [here](http://codepaste.net/tzfm6j)).

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
      includes:
        in_header: in_header.tex
      slide_level: 2
      toc: true
      latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Section 1

## Slide 1
Slide content

## Slide 2
Slide content

# Section 2
```

I get the following error message when trying to compile:

```
    ! LaTeX Error: No counter 'sectionpage' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.135 \section{Section 1}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

How do I define a counter for 'sectionpage'?

Comment: `\newcounter{sectionpage}` most likely, but I have no idea how to add this to the pandoc specifications

Comment: To me it seems that pandoc produces an erroneous latex sourcecode. This can't really be solved on TeX's side I'm afraid :(