# Latex beamer: slide numbers for subsubsections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to have slide numbers in the table of contents in beamer.
I found this useful post and it works for me, but I also need the page numbers for subsubsections. Unfortunately, I have no idea, what to change in this verbose code.

[Table of contents with page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/beamer-tableofcontents-with-page-numbers)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those information are stored in the `.toc` file. You just need to tell [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) how to use them. See `beamerbasetoc.sty` for more information.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@endinputifotherversion#1{}
\def\beamer@sectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5{{\huge #2 \hfill page #3 \par}}
\def\beamer@subsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6{{\normalsize #3 \hfill page #4 \par}}
\def\beamer@subsubsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{{\tiny #4 \hfill page #5 \par}}

\frame{
    \tableofcontents
}

\section{Section 1}\frame{}\frame{}
    \subsection{Subsection 1-1}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1-1-2}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1-1-2}\frame{}\frame{}
    \subsection{Subsection 1-2}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1-2-2}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1-2-2}\frame{}\frame{}
\section{Section 2}\frame{}\frame{}
    \subsection{Subsection 2-1}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2-1-2}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2-1-2}\frame{}\frame{}
    \subsection{Subsection 2-2}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2-2-2}\frame{}\frame{}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2-2-2}\frame{}\frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image]